# About context menu

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I'm doing a context menu and I have some problems/questions about it.
This is the code:

HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9p0ht6/1/

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onclick="hide()">
    <div style="display:none;" id="menu">
        <table  border="1" width="100px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div  class="item">
                        <a href="http://www.google.es">TEST 1</a>
                    </div>             
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div  class="item">TEST 2</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function show(e) {
            var posx = e.clientX +window.pageXOffset +'px'; 
            var posy = e.clientY + window.pageYOffset + 'px';
            document.getElementById('menu').style.position = 'absolute';
            document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById('menu').style.left = posx;
            document.getElementById('menu').style.top = posy;           
        }
        function hide() {
            document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    </script>
    <div  oncontextmenu="show(event);"class="menu-item" id="option1">
        option 1
    </div>
    <div  oncontextmenu="show(event);"class="menu-item" id="option2">
        option 2
    </div>
</body>
```

It works fine, when I do right click, my context menu appears, but (As you can see) when I click anywhere (body event) it must be hidden, but it doesn't works ... only works if I click a 'menu-item' class.

The other question is:
It's possible get the element ID with oncontextmenu event? I mean, for example, I do right click on 'Option 1' and I want see the context menu and an alert with the element ID. It's possible do it on same event?

Comment: It's generally poor practice to have inline javascript in your html tags. Create a separate file, and do: `var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; body.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { e.preventDefault() });`

Comment: I'm new with this... you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9p0ht6/6/  but your var body don't works

Comment: I've answered your question, but you're mistaken about the var body not working. jsFiddle uses iframes, and the body of your real document is just really short. Use my answer, but when trying it out in jsfiddle, try right-clicking right next to your menu.

Comment: Yep :D It work out jsFiddle. Thanks. the "e.preventDefault()" was the key no? It means that my contextmenu will have the default value (display:none) no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the liberty to move a bunch of things around in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9p0ht6/7/

For starters, I moved the JS into it's own file.
For the body:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
body.addEventListener("click", hide);
```

By using `addEventListener` you can then pass the event to the function, and use `e.preventDefault()` which, as it says, prevents the default action for that event.

Then, I do the same for each "menu-item":

```
var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
var i = 0, items = menuItems.length;
while (i < items) {
    menuItems[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
        show(e);
    });
    i++;
};
```

Looped through the nodeList, and applied the event listener to each. The `e.preventDefault()` was already used on the body, which encompasses the menu, so no need to use that here as well.

Now, your new "context menu" will appear when you right click on your menu, and the default one will never appear.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine, BTW do you know how can I get the element ID with the oncontextmenu??? Maybe with a GetElementsId?? I'm new with this and I want learn about it.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you accept my answer if it's what you need. Also, what/where do you need to get the element's id? Be a bit more specific

Comment: for example I want do an "Alert" with element ID. After this I will adapt it for a php funtion :D

Comment: @user3424570 Which element, though? Either way, you could use the `element.id` property, or `element.getAttribute("id")` -- Also, once again, please click on the check mark above to accept my answer.

Comment: Done. I must add the element.getAttribute("id") on the same "show(e)" script?

Comment: @user3424570 No, but I see what you're trying to do now. above `show(e)` add a line: `var elemID = this.id` -- and now you can do whatever you want with elemID. perhaps `alert(elemID)` or whatever your plan is.

Comment: appears an alert with "undefined" maybe I must send something when I call show(event) function?